# Terminal getting stuck at 'Awaiting transaction in the mempool' while using Brownie deploy function

Tags: javascript, python, blockchain, solidity, brownie

When I run brownie run scripts/deploy.py, the terminal prints 'Awaiting in the mempool' infinitely. My smart contract has no constructor.

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage

def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts[0]
    print(account)

    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({'from': account})
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

One terminal is running "npm run ganache" and here's my package.json file,

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache": "^7.0.3",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ganache": "ganache --wallet.seed myCustomSeed"
  }
}
```

Terminal 2 is running
`brownie run scripts/deploy.py`
When I kill this terminal, I get the following message,

```
raise TransactionNotFound(message)  
web3.exceptions.TransactionNotFound: Transaction with hash: '0x28da598c177dba438a6d8dee44ef3737ee1141d9435c00a42cd7ca481a58f99b' not found.
```

Here's the Youtube video that I am following if it's helpful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=16421s  @4:43:48

SmartStorage.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: are u connected to ganache? please share the full code.

Comment: I did connect to Ganache. I have updated the question with the full code and also some more information.

Comment: do you see the printed values on the terminal? account and stored_value

Comment: I see account but not stored_value.
Terminal continuously prints "Awaiting transaction in the mempool"

Comment: looks like your contract has issue. share your contract, too

Comment: I have edited the question with the solidity file.
The compiler version is: 0.6.0+commit.26b70077
I tried using a higher compiler version too, but it didn't help.
The ganache terminal keeps printing this,
`eth_gasPrice  
eth_getBlockByNumber  
eth_sendTransaction  
eth_getTransactionByHash`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine, I still don't fully understand it, but it seems that if you have any `ganache` server running in the background while trying to deploy/test on a network that was manually added using a fork, then you should stop it, for all the other ones you should still have to run your `ganache` server in the background.

From what I can tell, the problem seems to be that a port conflict is happening between the `ganache` server that you run in the background and the `ganache` server that is started when you run your deployment/testing scripts on those specific networks.

Answer (score 0):

`retrieve` function seems correct but there is a bug in `addPerson`. I am not sure if this will solve it but you are pushing `People` type to `people` but `people` is not defined:

```
function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        // people is not defined
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
```

since it has `push` method, it must be an array defined like this:

```
    People[] public people;
```

Comment: So I removed all the functions leaving retrieve. Removed all the variables except for the one used in retrieve function. Still getting 
`Awaiting transaction in the mempool`

Comment: you kept this,too : uint256 favoriteNumber;

Comment: Yup, I kept that

Comment: instead of accounts[0] can you use accounts[1].

Comment: Still the same. I think I'll follow the documentation instead of the video.... Thanks for helping out

Comment: Update: So if I run brownie console instead, it works. So I think that's good. Thanks a lot

Comment: What do u mean by brownie console.

Comment: I just ran `brownie console` in my terminal. And then typed `run('deploy')` (deploy.py is my python file). I worked.
Also, could you tell me what is `BrownieEnvironmentWarning: Development network has a block height of 2
    BrownieEnvironmentWarning`
It's just a warning but is there something that I can do about this warning?

Comment: How were you running before :)

Comment: One terminal was running ganache. The other did `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`
The video said so.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm following that same course and faced the same issue.
It worked after adding ganache-local as a network for brownie, as done later in the video you linked. https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=20295 (5:38:15)

```
brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:8545 chainid=1337
```

As for the warning, you can safely ignore it. It's just telling you that the ganache blockchain you're running has a block height of x.